# Fixed invalid SSL certificate manually in my 2006 computer

Tags: macos, git, ssl, certificate

My machine is a black 2006 MacBook running MacOS 10.6.8. According to this post on [Apple user discussion board](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253224807), as of 2021-09-30, the SSL certificate expired on my local machine. I downloaded the active `der` and `pem` from [Let's Encrypt root certificates](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/). I set up the `der` to Trust All on `Keychain Access.app` as a System `DigiCert Global Root G2`. Then got [git to trust this certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16543283/2472827); `sudo cp isrgrootx1.pem /usr/local/etc/openssl/; sudo git config --system http.sslCAInfo /usr/local/etc/openssl/isrgrootx1.pem`

It seems to work okay now, but I have very little idea of what I just did. Are there any security considerations that I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like it will probably make Git work, but you've missed probably the biggest security consideration of all: you're running an OS that has not received any security updates in over seven years.  Your OS definitely has known security vulnerabilities, some of which may be remotely exploitable, and it is unlikely that the TLS library you're using is fully patched, either, so it is also probably insecure.

Even if you are not concerned about this, the fact that your computer is easily compromised means it's a hazard to other computers on the Internet, since it can be used as part of a botnet.  If you want to continue to use this hardware, the best choice would be to put an up to date Linux distro on it, which, with a lightweight desktop environment, could continue to provide a secure but usable environment.

Of course, if your computer is not connected to the Internet, then the security of it matters little, but in that case the certificate wouldn't have presented a problem.